# Error happened: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.112:443

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic application and in the process of adding the android platform, I keep getting the following error.

```
ionic platform add android
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Downloading Default Ionic Resources
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-default-resources/archive/master.zip
Error happened { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.112:443]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '192.30.253.112',
  port: 443 }
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.112:443
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
```

I have tried everything possible but could not get the solution to this error. What is really happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Hey please let the database active in one terminal window and open another terminal window to run the command you are running as these kinds of error usually occurs when the database is not working or switched off.